# How to get a symbol in a MathJax expression rendered in a sans serif font bold face?

Tags: mathjax

I try to find out how to get a symbol, (Y, W, S, K, I, and B) in a MathJax expression, like `$Y$` rendered as in a *sans serif* font in bold face, like "**Y**".

It is easy to either get a sans serif rendering: `$\mathsf{Y}$` or in a bold face: `$\mathbf{Y}$`, but it eludes me how to do *both* for the same symbol.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\mmlToken{mi}[mathvariant="sans-serif-bold-italic"]{Y}`, but the MathJax TeX web fonts don't include a sans-serif bold italic variant, so you would be relying on system fonts unless you forced the sue of STIX fonts in you ruer page.  Thus the results may vary from user to user, and will take longer to process, as MathJax has to measure each character that is not in its own fonts.